# AIR webbrowser : how to update the browser

Tags: apache-flex, air

I have an AIR application (flex 4.6 or flex 4.7), using  AdobeAIR3.7 or AdobeAir4.0

I use a HTML browser component

```
<mx2:HTML id="browser" width="100%" height="100%">
```

Problem is: when navigating to page, JS gives errors, whereas it works fine with firefox, chrome, ie or safari

When I display the brower navigator.appVersion gives me :

```
5.0 (windows;u;fr-FR) AppleWebkit/533.19.4(KHTML, like Gecko) AdobeAIR/3.7
5.0 (windows;u;fr-FR) AppleWebkit/533.19.4(KHTML, like Gecko) AdobeAIR/4.0
```

Maybe this is an OLD version : is there a way to UPDATE the internal browser used by Flex ?

JS script I got in the AIR HTML (I don't get in normal browsers)

```
ReferenceError: Can't find variable: Uint8Array
TypeError: Result of expression 'messageHandler.on' [undefined] is not a function.
```

Comment: As far as I am aware, there is no way to do it. I'd love to be proven wrong (which is why I am posting as a comment and not an answer), but I did try this back in AIR 3.1/3.3 days and ended up failing to update it.

Comment: Have you tried with AIR 13 or 13?  You might also look into using StageWebView instead of HTML.